# How to split and duplicate value in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a table where it's like this:

| date | conversions |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | [{"action_type":"app_custom_event.LOGIN","value":"25"}] |
| 2022-05-02 | [{"action_type":"subscribe_mobile_app","value":"1"},{"action_type":"subscribe_total","value":"1"},{"action_type":"app_custom_event.LOGIN","value":"237"}] |
| 2022-05-03 | [{"action_type":"app_custom_event.LOGIN","value":"21"}] |

What I want is to break the conversions event into columns.
The end result is

| date | conversions type | conversions value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | app_custom_event.LOGIN | 25 |
| 2022-05-02 | subscribe_mobile_app | 1 |
| 2022-05-02 | subscribe_total | 1 |
| 2022-05-02 | app_custom_event.LOGIN | 237 |
| 2022-05-03 | app_custom_event.LOGIN | 21 |

Right now I am stuck at

```
campaign_data_df[['conversions type','conversions value']]= campaign_data_df['conversions'].str.split(",", n = 2, expand = True)  
campaign_data_df['conversions value']=campaign_data_df['conversions value'].str.extract('(\d+)')
campaign_data_df['conversions type']=campaign_data_df['conversions type'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ')
campaign_data_df= campaign_data_df.drop(columns=['conversions'])
campaign_data_df.to_csv('data/facebook/fb.csv', mode="w", header=True,index=False)
```

However this will work only with 2 types. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First evaluate the strings in `conversions` as python dictionaries then `explode` the column then create new dataframe from the exploded column and `join` it with the `date` column

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = df['conversions'].map(literal_eval).explode()
df[['date']].join(pd.DataFrame([*s], index=s.index))
```

---

```
         date             action_type value
0  2022-05-01  app_custom_event.LOGIN    25
1  2022-05-02    subscribe_mobile_app     1
1  2022-05-02         subscribe_total     1
1  2022-05-02  app_custom_event.LOGIN   237
2  2022-05-03  app_custom_event.LOGIN    21
```

Comment: HI this works, however if I have a NA in the values in conversions it returns malformed node or string: nan. Is there a way around na items I still need it to return the date

Comment: @EvansGunawan In that case we can drop the `NaN` values before using `literal_eval`. Please check: `s = df['conversions'].dropna().map(literal_eval).explode()`